# Why might rails 3.1 not evaluate erb before coffeescript in a .js.coffee.erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript, erb, asset-pipeline

I have a file in my rails 3.1 project called: foo.js.coffee.erb

```
console.log <?= 1+1 ?>
```

This causes:

```
throw Error("ExecJS::ProgramError: Error: Parse error on line 1: Unexpected 'COMPOUND_ASSIGN'\n  (in /Users/trafnar/Sites/imagesnap/app/assets/javascripts/tiles.js.coffee.erb)")
```

Clearly the ERB is tripping it up. I thought Rails 3.1 allowed the use of an ERB preprocessor before coffeescript, why might this be failing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you have your delimiters right? I'd expect to see:

```
console.log <%= 1+1 %>
```

in an `.erb` file.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something embarrassingly simple. I use a shortcut to generate <%= %> which didn't work in my .coffee file, so I typed it out, incorrectly.